# How to restrict UITextField to take only ID card number in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

i'm a newbie and i want user to enter something like 12300-1141090-7 in textfield of alert box.
i want user to enter first 5 characters like 12345 then '-' then 7 characters 1234567 then '-' and then 1 character 1 , collectively i want user to enter 12345-1234567-1
i just need a help in textfield check

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Personal Info!",
                              message: "Required CNIC for Verfication",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)

let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
    [unowned self] action in

    guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
        let nameToSave = textField.text else {
            return
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to enter '-' manually or Automatic in your text field?

Comment: it will best if dashes remain hardcode and user just need to enter the numbers because it will get more clear to the user.

Comment: checkout my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think, first Make keyboard type as **number** that will not allow user to enter any character other then digit.
Then implement `UITextFieldDelegate` method like this way.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var txtAfterUpdate:NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    txtAfterUpdate = txtAfterUpdate.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let updatedString = txtAfterUpdate as String
    //for max length...
    if updatedString.characters.count > 15 {
        return false
    }
    if updatedString.characters.count == 6 && string != "" {
        textField.text = textField.text! + "-"
        return true
    } else if updatedString.characters.count == 14 && string != ""{
        textField.text = textField.text! + "-"
        return true
    }

    return true
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for your question.
Sol 1 : Make keyboard type number that will not allow useer to enter any character other then digit.

Sol 2 : Use textfield delegate method `public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` check whether character enter by user is character you want then return true else return false. On return false character will not be print in textfield and it will be ignore

Comment: i want user to enter first 5 characters like 12345 then '-' then 7 characters 1234567 then '-' and then 1 character 1 , collectively i want user to enter 12345-1234567-1

Comment: You need to put '-' through code. Use did same delegate method see the textfield.text length and add '-' to string if count is 5,13 and so on..